# Get statement generates: "Invalid use of Null"

Tags: vba, file, ms-word

I need to open (and close) multiple files. That's why I wrote a little `Function FileOpen`. The code works perfectly in my subroutines where I am using the byte array `B` but getting an error message in the function. I pass the full name "FN" of the file. The file exists. The `ReDim` works fine, but I get the

> error 94 "Invalid use of null"

on the Get statement.

```
Sub main()     
    Dim FN As String: FN = "c:\tmp\test.docx"
    Dim B() As Byte

    If FileOpen(FN, B) < 0 Then Debug.Print " Error"
    
End Sub
Function FileOpen(FN, ByRef B) As Long
    Dim nFile As Integer
    
    nFile = FreeFile
    Open FN For Binary Access Read As nFile
    If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
        ReDim B(LOF(nFile) - 1)
        Get nFile, , B
        Close nFile
        FileOpen = 0
    Else
        Close nFile
        FileOpen = -1
    End If

End Function
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: `ByRef B` => `ByRef B() As Byte`?

Comment: There isn't. In fact, there wasn't "Invalid use of null" error in the first place, there was another one, caused by the inability of the `Get` statement to accept a byref-variant containing a byte array. Please show your actual code that actually reproduces this problem.

Comment: Many Thanks! You pointed me to the right point: This works: `Function FileOpen(FN, B() As Byte) As Long`

Comment: Just for clarification, I got the error “Invalid use of Null”. However, after reboot I got the Runtime Error 458 "Variable uses a type not supported in Visual Basic". I guess that I screw up my system, and then I got the correct error message 458.